# Why explicitly generic function value binds differently from similar non-generic?

Tags: generics, f#

Let's take a simple function value `f1`:

```
let f1 = printfn "*bind f1*"; fun () -> printfn "f1()"
```

`f1` binds in FSI as

```
*bind f1*
val f1 : (unit -> unit)
```

and, being invoked, behaves as expected

```
> () |> f1 |> f1;;
f1()
f1()
val it : unit = ()
```

Now let's take a similar function value, but made explicitly generic `f2<'a>`:

```
let f2<'a> = printfn "*bind f2*"; fun () -> printfn "f2()"
```

`f2` binds in FSI as

```
val f2<'a> : (unit -> unit)
```

without any `*bind f2*` output whatsoever, but then, being invoked, outputs it on each `f2` invocation:

```
> () |> f2 |> f2;;
*bind f2*
f2()
*bind f2*
f2()
val it : unit = ()
```

My question is: what may be the cause for such observed disparity?

Comment: f2 is a type function (10.2.3 in f# spec)

Comment: @desco: Thank you, Vladimir! If you not mind to put this into an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# does not *generally* allow creating of generic values because of the "value restriction" difficulties that this introduces (that is, you cannot create a syntactic value that is generic, even if it is a code that returns function). So, your `f2` should not be allowed, but...

The rule has a single exception - it is often useful to have generic values like `List.empty` and so if you declare a value with explicit generic type arguments, it actually is compiled into a function that returns the result.

That's exactly what happens in your example:

```
let f2<'a> = printfn "*bind f2*"; fun () -> printfn "f2()"
```

here, `f2` is a generic value (even though it does not really use the type argument anywhere), but it has an explicit generic type argument and so it is actually compiled into a method that is called each time `f2` is accessed and it returns the result (function `unit -> unit`)

I could not find any clear explanation for this in the specification, but there is a [good MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (see "Case 4") and also a [blog by former F# team member](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Tomas is right, as usual.  Note that you can create a generic function that behaves as `f1` does, but you've got to use a nominal generic type as a cache of sorts:

```
type private Container<'a> () =
    static member val f2 : unit -> unit = printfn "*bind f2*"; fun () -> printfn "f2()"

let f2<'a>() = Container<'a>.f2()
```